How do I create a GHC package environment file that's equivalent to not having one?
When using GHC without a package environment file, you'll be able to use several libraries that it ships with, such as containers and text. When you do have a package environment, though, you can only use the packages it mentions. Is there an easy way to create an environment file that contains all of the packages that are exposed without one? It looks like I could hack together a solution based on parsing the output of ghc-pkg list -v, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way. If this is version-specific, then I'm looking for a solution that works with GHC 9.8.2 and Cabal 3.10.3.0.

Does cabal freeze get you where you need to go? Modern cabal also automatically generates a GHC environment file on each build, I believe. If it's not dumped directly next to the .cabal file, check in dist-newstyle.

No. That command looks like it's only useful if you already have a .cabal file with dependencies, but I'm specifically asking for a way to get an environment with the default set of stuff that you can use, e.g., in GHCi outside of any project.

If you look at some of the ghc-pkg subcommands and options, you'll see that parsing isn't too hard.  The following shell script ought to work.  Since it runs ghc-pkg field on every package to check whether it's exposed or hidden, it's too slow to be used on every ghc invocation, but it should be fine for generating a static environment file for each new GHC version that comes along:
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo clear-package-db
echo global-package-db

for p in $(ghc-pkg list --simple-output --show-unit-ids)
do
        if [ "$(ghc-pkg --simple-output --unit-id field $p exposed)" = True ]
        then
           echo package-id $p
        fi
done

